# Convert Javascript Date object to other timezone Date Object

Tags: javascript

How to convert Javascript Date Object to another timezone but the result must be Date object with the correct timezone

```
let date = new Date();
console.log(date);

date = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Vancouver' });
date = new Date(date);
console.log(date);
```

that gives the following result, the last result line (Date/Time) is correct but the time zone is incorrect which is still **GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)** but must be **GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)** timezone

```
Wed Jan 20 2021 00:14:11 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)
Tue Jan 19 2021 21:14:11 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

Comment: are you trying to display time with your local timezone?

Comment: You should consider using a library like `moment-timezone`. Makes working with dates/times and timezone one heck of a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this :

```
    let date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
    date = date.toLocaleString("en-CA", {
      timeZone: "America/Vancouver",
      timeZoneName: "long",
    });
    console.log(date);
```

Output:

> Wed Jan 20 2021 09:18:16 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time)

> 2021-01-19, 10:18:16 p.m. Pacific Standard Time

Once you get the correct TimeZone, you may change how the date and time are displayed by string manipulation if you need too.

**Update:**

This may not look pretty but i believe it should satisfy the requirements:

```
    let date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/Vancouver",
    timeZoneName: "short",
    });

    let date1 = new Date(date);
    //adding a new property to Date object called tz and initializing it to null
    Date.prototype.tz = null;
    //stting the tz value to the Time zone output from toLocalString
    date1.tz = date.slice(date.length - 3);
    
    console.log(date1.toISOString() + " " + date1.tz);
    console.log(date);
    console.log(typeof date1);
```

Output:

> 2021-01-20T09:01:06.000Z PST

> 1/20/2021, 1:01:06 AM PST

> Object

What i've done is create a new property of the object date to replace the built-in time zone property in Date, hence you get an object with a user specified Time zone.

Comment: *...but the result must be Date object with the correct timezone*. Your solution will produce a string.

Comment: @codemonkey, can you check the updated response, i believe it may satisfy your requirements.